# Movimientos ganadores comparados con movimientos de jugador Tic-tac-toe

Tags: javascript, array

estoy intentando hacer el tictactoe, nada muy sofisticado, y lo que quiero hacer es comparar si los movimientos que realizó el jugador (pusheados en un array) son iguales a los movimientos ganadores del juego. Les paso a dejar el código:

```
                /* ARRAYS*/

const fichas = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
const board = Array.from(fichas);

const winningCombo = [
   [0, 1, 2],
   [3, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8],
   [0, 3, 6],
   [1, 4, 7],
   [2, 5, 8],
   [0, 4, 8],
   [2, 4, 6]
];


let winningX = [];
let winningO = [];

 /*Funciones*/

const addChip = (playerTurn) => {
let chip = playerTurn ? 'X' : 'O';
return chip;
}

function isPlaying() {
let playerTurn = true;
board.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        element.textContent = addChip(playerTurn);
        if (playerTurn) {
            winningX.push(board.indexOf(element));
            let algo = sonIguales(winningCombo, winningX);
            console.log(algo);
            playerTurn = false;
        } else {
            winningO.push(board.indexOf(element));
            playerTurn = true;
        }

    }, { once: true });
});
}

isPlaying();
```

Lo que quiero saber es, como compruebo, luego de que el jugador realiza un movimiento, por ejemplo si sus movimientos son iguales que algún array dentro de winningCombo. Por ejemplo el jugador X puede tener dentro de su array [0,4,1,5,2] lo que tendría un 3 en lineal horizontal. Espero haber sido claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar la función [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) de Javascript. Está función del prototype array, hace una iteración de cada elemento y se usa un callback para verificar si cumple la función.

En tu caso la función callback podría quedar como la siguiente.

```
function isWinning(playerMoves){
    //Esta será tu callback para llamar en every.
    isValidWinningCombo = comboElement => playerMoves.Contains(comboElement);
    //iteramos en todos los combos ganadores posibles
    for(combo of winningCombo) {
        /* si todos los elementos de un combo se encuentran en los movimientos
           del jugador, lo podemos declarar ganador. */
        if(combo.every(isValidWinningCombo)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    //de lo contrario decimos que no es un ganador
    return false;
}
```

Ya solo bastaría que agregaras la función donde creas más conveniente.

```
isWinning(winningX); //retornará true si es ganador o false si no lo es.
```

Comment: Mil gracias, excelente. Voy a intentar leerlo en mas detalles para poder comprenderlo mejor y aprender más. Un saludo